# Android - Fragment onActivityResult avoid reloading

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm using a `Fragment` that loads an Image into a `ImageView`.

I want to change that image with `startActivityForResult()` but when I finish that `Activity` and go back to the `Fragment`,the `Fragment` reloads the first image again.

Probably because of the `onStart()` method.

How can I avoid the `Fragment` to reload after `onActivityResult()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what the problem was.

The fragment loads in the information in the onStart() method.
I had a look at the fragment lifecycle and found out that I had to
load the information in the onActivityCreated() method.

This way the view is already created and I can refer to my xml-objects.
Check out this image that explains the fragment lifecycle:
http://developer.android.com/images/activity_fragment_lifecycle.png