# Hold Fragment View State in Sliding menu library on deattach and then attach in transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to create an android application that uses [sliding menu library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu).

Now my question is that suppose I have three fragment A, B, C and I load Fragment A initially then B then after C now when I attach Fragment A after detaching current viewing fragment, Fragment A starts from onCreateView and my view again generated.

So is there any way to store my view or save it so it does not generate again like in facebook which shows home screen initially then if you go to any menu option and press back then you again will come to home screen and event internet is not available it whole view is like it was before as what I think does not recreate.

Comment: you have to manage fragments in `BackStack`, [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/part_2_-_managing_fragments) is the example.

Comment: hii MrSuS,thanks to answer but my question is suppose i have three fragment A,B,C already in fragmentManager.and fragment C is currently attached to container ,now i select fragment A from sliding menu so in this case i detached fragment C from container and again attach fragment A.So in this case Fragment A life cycle starts from onCreateView().while i want my fragment back in previous state without recreating its view.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13850676/2388614) answer.

Comment: thanks MrSuS i think i got my answer.

Comment: @MrSuS now here i got another problem,if i add fragment B to fragment transaction and hide the current fragment that is A.then in this scenario data that comes from web service is not showing in Fragment B.while if i replace current fragment 'A' by 'B' then data appears in list.

Answer (score 0):

```
transaction.hide(currentFragment);
transaction.show(detailScreen);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

By this way i can hold my transaction without detaching it.and it will contains all information of a fragment.